# A note about a definition of smooth $k$-dimensional manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds

I'm reding Definition 1.4 in [this](https://minterscompactness.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/Differential_Geometry_Part_II_Notes.pdf) lecture note.

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$. Then we say that $X$ is a (smooth) $k$ (-dimensional) manifold if for all $x \in X, \exists V \subset X$ open (in the topology of $X$ ) such that $V$ is diffeomorphic to some open $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$.
>
> A diffeomorphism $\varphi: U \rightarrow V \subset X$ with $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{k}$ is then called a local parameterisation of the neighbourhood $V .$ The inverse diffeomorphism $\varphi^{-1}: V \rightarrow U$ is called a local coordinate system, or chart, on $V$.

Then there are an illustration and a remark.

[image]

> **Note:** Wlog we can assume that $U$ in the above definition is a disc, and hence that $U$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. So we can say "such that $V$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ " and everything would still work, but the above definition is "more" general.

Not every open set is diffeomorphic to a disc, let alone $\mathbb R^k$. I would like to ask if this remark is correct or If I miss something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "Note" does not say $U$ is diffeomorphic to a disc or to $\mathbb R^k$. Instead, what that note says is that if we are *given* one diagram of sets and maps as illustrated, satisfying all the requirements of that definition, then there exists *another* diagram that also satisfies all the requirements of that definition **together with** the additional requirement that $U$ is a disc.

For the proof, simply choose an open disc $D \subset \mathbb R^k$ such that $y \in D \subset U$, then restrict $\phi$ to $D$ and restrict $\phi^{-1}$ to $\phi(D)$. In this new diagram, $D$ becomes the "new $U$" (call it $U'$) and $\phi(D)$ becomes the "new $V$" (call it $V'$).

Comment: Could you check if my understanding of your ideas is correct? Given $x$ and a diffeomorphism $\varphi_x: U_x \to V_x$, we can define a new diffeomorphism $\varphi_x': U_x \to V_x', y \mapsto  \varphi_x (y) - \varphi_x (x)$. Then $\varphi_x'$ maps $x$ to $0$, and $V_x'$ is a neighborhood of $0$. Let $V_x''$ be an open ball centered at $0$ and contained in $V'_x$ and $U_x' := [\varphi_x']^{-1} (V_x'')$. Then $\varphi_x'$ restricted on $U_x'$ is a required diffeomorphism.

Comment: That's more complicated than what I was imagining. There is no necessity to use open balls centered on $0$. You may simply use open balls centered on $\phi(x)$.